# Removing wires / connectors on dishwasher circuit board

Tags: connector, wiring

I need to remove a circuit board to send for repair, but I’m not sure how to remove these wires? I notice there’s two silver objects in two of the holes, not sure if they’re clamps or fasteners. I’ll use this photo as a means of where to reconnect them after removal. I’d really appreciate the help, it's a Whirlpool dishwasher board.

[image: photo of circuit board, wires and connectors]

Comment: You should probably put labels on the wires, because I can promise you that it's important *which* yellow wire goes in which terminal.

Comment: Spring loaded clamps with release buttons or levers it seems

Comment: Take a picture of the other side.

Answer (score 1):

You don't remove single wires. The wires are located on the connectors. You do have to remove the plastic lock mechanism to access the connectors and then simply unplug them. Usually those connectors have grooves on them, as well the mating grooves on the PCB, so you can't mix the connectors.

The two silver objects are knives for cutting the wire isolation and establish the copper connection. Once you remove the wire, the connector become useless, you have to install new one, so don't attempt to pull the wires off.